# Using blade inside of javascript function when the output should be HTML

Tags: javascript, laravel

The issue I'm having is with escaped html inside of a javascript function, passed from blade. $message contains basic html or strings with quotes, so if I use {!! !!} it doesn't work because it seems that the output from blade into the function needs to be in quotes.

**Inside javascript script tag**

```
@foreach ($messages as $message)
        addMessages('{{$message['message']}}', '{{$message['message_side']}}');
        @endforeach
```

**addMessages javascript function**

```
addMessages = function (text, message_side) {
                var $messages, message;
                if (text.trim() === '') {
                    return;
                }
                $('.message_input').val('');
                $messages = $('.messages');
                message = new Message({
                    text: text,
                    message_side: message_side
                });
                message.draw();
                return $messages.animate({ scrollTop: $messages.prop('scrollHeight') }, 300);
            };
```

Comment: could you check your output JS code and attach it to a question? according to  the [laravel's docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#displaying-data) `{{ ... }}` makes `htmlspecialchars()` call so every single quote should be converted into `&apos;` so they will never break JS code in this way.

Comment: It is getting converted to escaped html. Output JS code is below: addMessages('Hi, thanks for joining, we&#039;ll need your Full Name and Delivery Address...', 'left');   the problem is that I need those single quotes to make the function work.

Comment: so... it does not work for you, right? but why? or do you mean that you don't need such escaping because JS will render it literally(like `It&apos;s`)?

Comment: Does not work. It doesn't work because in my view it shows up as the html in text, but when I have things like <img src="image.src"> in the message, it literally outputs <img src="image.src"> instead of rendering the image. When using the app live, using the same javascript function, it renders the image. It's a chat window, and what I am doing here is fetching the previous messages from a database and outputting them to the view. When using the app live, it works fine when the message contains html, it renders it. The problem is that I have escaped html inside of a function with single quotes

Comment: I've just realized it is not best approach at all. I guess you need to retrieve messages not only on page load but also later(in async way - JS asks server for additional messages). So far the easiest way is not composing JS code by PHP but put static JS call into page's code: `retrieveInitialMessages().then(/*... insert messages through addMessages() calls ...*/)`

Comment: Later on the messages are retrieved through Pusher.js.. Right now, you are right, I am composing JS code by PHP to have the chat window populate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I believe the issue is in double-escaping: first data is escaped by Blades with calling `htmlspecialchars()`(according to [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#displaying-data)) and later it's escaped somewhere in JS code(it may not be escaped directly rather threated as a text through `createTextNode(message)` or `innerText = message`).

So you need to turn one of these escape calls off.

As you mentioned you could use `{ !! }` to output raw text on Blade side. And yes, this still needs to be wrapped with quotes(single or double) to be valid JS code. But you should care about the-same-type-quotes(single or double) inside you text to omit such a case:

```
addMessage('It's me. I'm broken')
```

To achieve that you can just escape approrpiate quote mark manually with a slash to get something like

```
addMessage('It\'s me. I\'m broken')
```

[UPD] as @Ian Fain mentioned it's possible to call functions right inside the `{ !! }`
So finally this escaping can be done without any custom directive as easy as

```
@foreach ($messages as $message)
    addMessages({!! json_encode($message['message']) !!}, {!! json_encode($message['message_side']) !!})
@endforeach
```

Also mention `json_encode` adds additional double quotes so they are not needed to be inserted directly anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. This seems to work. 
            addMessages('{!! str_replace("'", "\'", $message['message']) !!}', '{{$message['message_side']}}');

Comment: I see. did not know it's allowed to use php functions inside. then better use `json_encode` if available. it will process nested slashes/escaping correctly.

Comment: json_encode() does not work. It puts the output in double quotes and It does not replace the single quotes and it messes up the slashes in the http links. Is there a particular argument to pass?

Comment: yes, there is a `options` argument there. what's wrong with links? as for double qoutes - it's excellent. you don't need to wrap value manually anymore, don you?

Comment: Hmm, good point about the double quotes. The slashes in links are like this /\

Comment: do you mean "/"` becomes "/\" ? it's fine, js would process that as a "/" with additional escaping. Just check `alert("php.net\/json_encode")` would display 'php.net/json_encode' without that extra slash

Comment: Oh right, because it's escaping the slash. Silly me.